# Images will not display on heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I have deployed my repo to [heroku](https://ghoulish-wizard-8335.herokuapp.com/) and now my background image and profile pic are not displaying? One is an image in html:

```
<header>
    <img src="C:\Users\Ivan\Pictures\ivan slck.jpg" height="200px" width="150px" class="profile" />
        <h1>Ivan Baena</h1>
        <p> Aspiring Full Stacks Web Developer</p>  
    </header>
```

The other is a background image in css:

```
body{
     background-image: url(C:/Users/Ivan/Pictures/Abstract-light.jpg);
}
```

Comment: the image has to be a web URL not a folder path

Answer (score 0):

It is case sensitive, so I would check and make sure both the file and the code match exactly. I had this happen and it came down to the capitization. Good Luck!